# getting issue using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, closedxml

While creating an Excel document at runtime I get the following error:

> Excel found unreadable content in 'Filename.xlsx'. Do you want to
>   recover the content of this workbook? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, Click yes.

I have seen many posts regarding this on stack overflow but they have not helped me in this situation.

Below is my C# code which (attempts to) create the excel file:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
System.Data.DataTable Table = new System.Data.DataTable();
string AdvId = GlobalEntityID + "-" + AyId + "-" + QtrID;
var CSRExpenditureData = objCsrExp.GetCSRExpendituresFromSP(AdvId); //Get data in list from sp
Table = ListToDataTable(CSRExpenditureData); //Convert list to datatable 
Table.Columns.Remove("ID");        //Remove extra columns
Table.Columns.Remove("IsActive");  //Remove extra columns
Table.Columns.Remove("IsDefault"); //Remove extra columns
Table.Columns.Remove("IsSubmit");  //Remove extra columns


if (Table.Columns.Count > 0)
{
    var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add(Table, ReportName); 
}

workbook.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
workbook.Style.Font.Bold = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + ReportName + ".xlsx");
using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    workbook.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);  
}
```

[image: ExcelError]

**Note : Please don't mark this as duplicate because I have tried other posts as well**

Comment: please fix your post - cannot see error

Comment: @JohnB I have fixed it

Comment: The Open XML SDK does not constrain you to producing a valid document. However, there is the `OpenXmlValidator` class which you can use to report any errors in the generated document. Example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/09/24/finding-open-xml-errors-with-open-xml-sdk-validation.aspx

Comment: Are you using any kind of library like EPPlus or ClosedXML or something similar? (i.e. where is the `XLWorkbook` class coming from?)

Comment: @bassfader yes we are using this library

Comment: @vishuminhas so what library exactly? EPPlus or ClosedXML? Or some other library?

Comment: @bassfader using ClosedXML

Comment: @shunty thanks for suggestions but it didn't work :(

Comment: Do you need to set the stream position to 0? i.e. `MyMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before the call to `WriteTo`?

Comment: No, I am not setting stream position to 0 . What if I do it so ?

Comment: I'm not sure about with ClosedXml but certainly with OpenXml you need to reset the stream to the beginning otherwise you don't get the right result - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283476/openxml-create-word-document-and-download/36284372#36284372

Comment: I have tried with setting the stream position to 0 but not success.

Comment: If you save the `XLWorkbook` to a local file (not a stream) and open that file, is it valid? If so, the problem is with the delivery to the browser client.